# How i can delete a user auth (email , password ) firebase angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

in This app , there's on user who can create accounts and delete !

```
  deleteAuthTech (){
  return this.fireauth.user.subscribe((y)=>y.delete())
    
  }
```

Comment: I'm not very used to Angular's rxjs. In your case, what is the error that is happening? You can find a way to delete a logged in user through the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#delete_a_user).

Comment: could you tell us what you want to achieve? also set proper indent spaces for code